# creating a method that combines two ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new to programming in Java and I am trying to write a method that combines the contents of two ArrayLists and then prints them. I wrote the array lists and they will print individually fine but I am unsure how to print the result.

The result should be [1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11]

```java
package practice;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class practice_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**10/3/2020
         * Appends one array list to another
         */
    
        ArrayList <Integer> partA = new ArrayList <Integer>();
            partA.add(1);
            partA.add(4);
            partA.add(9);
            partA.add(16);
        ArrayList <Integer> partB = new ArrayList <Integer>();
            partB.add(9);
            partB.add(7);
            partB.add(4);
            partB.add(9);
            partB.add(11);
        
        System.out.println("A: " + partA);
        System.out.println("B: " + partB);
        System.out.println("Append: " + ???); //How do I print the two ArrayLists together?
    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> append(ArrayList <Integer> partA, ArrayList <Integer> partB)
    {
    ArrayList<Integer> append = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    

        for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++) 
            {
            append.add(partA.get(x));
            append.add(partB.get(x));
            }
        return append;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You simply print the appended list.

Comment: Take int account that your `append()` method will not produce the output you expect, as it does not append one list after the other, but creates a new list where each element of list A is followed by the element at the same index on list B.

Comment: like, System.out.println("Append: " + append);  ??

Comment: @couscous No, like `System.out.println("Append: " + append(partA, partB));`. But keep in mind my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

**Use addAll()**

```
    List <Integer> partAB = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    partAB.addAll(partA);
    partAB.addAll(partB);
    System.out.println("Append: " + partAB);
```

See context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List <Integer> partA = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 9, 16);
    List <Integer> partB = Arrays.asList(9, 7, 4, 9, 11);

    System.out.println("A: " + partA);
    System.out.println("B: " + partB);

    List <Integer> partAB = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    partAB.addAll(partA);
    partAB.addAll(partB);
    System.out.println("Append: " + partAB);
}
```

Output:

```
A: [1, 4, 9, 16]
B: [9, 7, 4, 9, 11]
Append: [1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your end result is supposed to be:

> The result should be [1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11]

The first half of the values is from the PartA list then the second half is all from the PartB list.  So you need to first add all the PartA values first to your 'appended' list, then you'd add the PartB values.

With that in mind your append method needs to be changed to:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> append(ArrayList <Integer> partA, ArrayList <Integer> partB)
{
     ArrayList<Integer> append = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    for(int x = 0; x < partA.size(); x++)  
    {
        append.add(partA.get(x));
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < partB.size(); x++)  
    {
        append.add(partB.get(x));
    }
    return append;
    }
}
```

Then simply iterate over the appended array list and it'll print it out in the order you specified.

Updated:

simpler way is to do what the other post says and you could use the addAll method to add the values of the first two ArrayLists to the appended array list.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class practice_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**10/3/2020
         * Appends one array list to another
         */

        ArrayList <Integer> partA = new ArrayList <Integer>();
        partA.add(1);
        partA.add(4);
        partA.add(9);
        partA.add(16);
        ArrayList <Integer> partB = new ArrayList <Integer>();
        partB.add(9);
        partB.add(7);
        partB.add(4);
        partB.add(9);
        partB.add(11);



        System.out.println("A: " + partA);
        System.out.println("B: " + partB);
        partA.addAll(partB);
        System.out.println("Append: " + partA); //How do I print the two ArrayLists together?
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to combine two lists.

**Using Streams**

```java
 List<String> newList = Stream.of(listOne, listTwo).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Using Streams concat**

```java
List<String> newList = Stream.concat(listOne.stream(), listTwo.stream()).collect(toList());
```

**Using Apache commons-collections**

```java
List<String> newList = ListUtils.union(listOne, listTwo);
```

Finally to print you can use

```java
System.out.println(newList)
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between both of your streams options here...

Comment: Sorry it was a copy paste mistake :). Edited. Thanks